# Unable to install Nvidia drivers on Kubuntu (KDE Neon 5.19)

Tags: drivers, kde, nvidia, kubuntu, plasma

I have some problems installing Nvidia drivers on my Kubuntu system and to get them working (GPU-Model: GeForce GTX 980 Ti). I tried it first in the standard way:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-450
```

The installation finished, but after restarting, the new drivers don't work very well. I'm using a 4K monitor with 3840x2160 (16:9) resolution, but with the driver in use, it only allows for a resolution of 1024x768 (4:3), so my whole screen gets distorted. Also, the command nvidia-smi fails:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Furthermore, after removing the drivers manually and restart, everything is back to normal. I tried with this method instead: `$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, but I get the same results. Then, I tried to execute the runfile provided by NVIDIA on their download site, but it fails because it is unable to disable Nouveau (the current Kernel driver in use).

I also executed this command: `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12` to check. This is what I get when running normal:

And here the same output with NVIDIA drivers enabled:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti] [10de:17c8] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti] [10de:17c8]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
        Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 High Definition Audio [10de:0fb0] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 High Definition Audio [10de:17c8]
```

Any advice how to get the NVIDIA drivers installed and working on Kubuntu? I tried pretty much every installation guide, but none of them really worked.

Answer (score 0):

> Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

1. You haven't blacklisted `nouveau` - please try adding `nouveau.modeset=0 nomodeset` to your GRUB flags
2. Make sure the NVIDIA driver has been compiled and installed successfully.

To check it:

```
grep nvidia /lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.alias
alias pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc0Csc80i* i2c_nvidia_gpu
alias pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00* nvidia_drm
alias pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00* nvidia_drm
alias char-major-195-* nvidia
alias pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00* nvidia
alias pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00* nvidia
```

In a perfect world everything should have been done automatically. Have you actually rebooted after installing the driver? You must have done that.

Comment: Hello, of course I did restart, that's where the problem is coming from. Where can I edit my Grub flags? I haven't done this before.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup https://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/

Comment: I tried to apply, but the suggested changes don't work. Even after adding to the flags and generating the new config file, I get the same result. The command you wrote gives be this output: `alias mbp_nvidia_bl apple_bl
alias pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc*i* nvidiafb
alias typec:id0955m* typec_nvidia
alias pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc0Csc80i* i2c_nvidia_gpu`

Comment: NVIDIA kernel modules haven't compiled for you. No idea why as I don't use Ubuntu.